# Difference between multilevel page system and multilevel cache system(L1,L2,L3)

Tags: operating-system

what is the difference between multilevel page system and multilevel cache system(L1,L2,L3) , its confusing to understand , multilevel page is used for better utilization of paging mechanism and multilevel cache is also used to cache most recently pages between RAM and CPU.
they both are interrelated , what is the difference between these two techniques ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 mechanisms serve different purposes.

Multilevel paging minimizes the space overhead of managing a page table by using a hierarchial structure instead of a flat one.

Multilevel cache system is used to provide faster access to the most used pieces of code and data. Roughly, the data present in L1 is more used than data in L2 which in turn is more used than data in L3 which is more used than data in RAM which is more used than paged data.

The paging mechanism can be seen as the upper level manager of the entire system memory (but it's not related to multilevel paging): L1 < L2 < L3 < RAM < Paged memory.